# How to store different value types in scala

Tags: scala

I may have a simple silly question, how to use Scala Map to store different value types, for example, I wanna the Map to store both string and double values,I tried the following code:

```
var yaraMap: Map[String, AnyRef] = Map()
yaraMap+={"as"->10.0}
yaraMap+={"bb"->'val'}
```

But it told the type mismatch, how can I fix this please, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define your map as

```
val yaraMap: Map[String, Any] = Map()
```

`Any` is the common supertype of `Double` and `String`.

The following image demonstrates how `AnyVal` and `AnyRef` are related. `String` is the subtype of `AnyRef`, `Double` is the subtype of `AnyVal`, their common supertype is `Any`.

[image]

[image source](http://joelabrahamsson.com/PageFiles/148/1310_1644.jpg)

Comment: Thanks David, Why AnyRef and Object not ok, but Any please.

Comment: because `Double` is not `AnyRef` its `AnyVal`

Comment: Thanks a lot David for the nice picture :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer from David Frank is great. Here is a small improvement to make the code typesafe (note: Any and AnyRef will allow you do add any other types to the Map without the compiler complaining).

If you only want your values to be either Double or String you can do this:

```
var yaraMap: Map[String, Either[Double, String]] = Map() 
yaraMap+={"as"->Left(10.0)}
yaraMap+={"bb"->Right("val")}
```

Arguably more verbose but at least it will break if you try to add, say a `List()` or any other type.

```
yaraMap+={"as"->Left(34)}
 <console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[String]
 required: Double
              yaraMap+={"as"->Left(List("a"))}
```